# iOS Widget Extension initial UIViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am adding a "Today" extension widget to my iOS app that I made with Xamarin. I am following this walkthrough:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_extensions/

The widget appears in my Notification section in the simulator, but I can't get any contents to appear in it. It won't even create the UIViewController class that I made and set as the initial controller to start with (I know because it never hits my breakpoint in the constructor). I set it as the principal class with this key as explained in the walkthrough:

[image]

Any idea why? I also get this message when I first launch the app after adding the extension:

`appname may slow down your phone the developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility`

I made a sample project, with Xamarin, and the widget does appear in this project when deployed on the simulator, just not with the contents that I'm trying to add in the CodeViewController class:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xKHTqtwfKtY0xZN0xaejhlZmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you share the code of your sample project it might be faster to recreate the problem and try to help you

Comment: Good idea. I added a small sample project.

Comment: It still doesn't work but so far 2 things I found. 1. I don't know how you created extension project but it is not an exe as it suppose to be but library. This is wrong. I should be able to see iOS extensions tab in project properties and I don't. 2. App container must include reference to extension which is not happening in your solution. I will keep digging and let you know if find something else. Please let me know if you solve it earlier

Comment: This one I created with Visual Studio. I created a previous one with Xamarin and I was at least able to see the widget appear in the simulator. So I guess I should avoid Visual Studio for the creation at least. But I just couldn't get it to use my CodeBasedViewController instead of the MainStoryboard. So the widget had "Hello World" in it. I didn't make reference to the extension from the app container though, not sure if that's supposed to be automatic?...I'll look at that when I get back to my office tomorrow morning.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, and I verified what you pointed out...I made another sample project, this time with Xamarin, and the widget does appear in this one, just not with the contents that I'm trying to add in the CodeViewController class. If you don't mind, can you verify this one too please?

Comment: Share the link with code please

Comment: I put it on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xKHTqtwfKtY0xZN0xaejhlZmM/view?usp=sharing
If you prefer, I can put it on my GitHub so it's easier to view?

Comment: it ok, downloading

Comment: still cannot make it work

Comment: I can't make it work either, but a colleague of mine told me he had a similar problem while working on Apple Watch, and solved it by editing the storyboard's XML to use his UIViewController. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: why you cannot use storyboard controller?

Comment: Solved with custom viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save you 2 days I spent on it here is the solution.

1. Don't run it on simulator. It doesn't work (at least on mine).
2. Don't try to hit breakpoint in VS. When you testing your extension your app is in background mode. VS will not give you to stop in debugger. To prove run any of your apps, press home and try to set breakpoint in VS. VS will hang till you bring your app to foreground.
3. Do not use View.Frame in DidLoad. The size of the frame there is the whole screen size, so when you put your label to center you will not see it. Use WillAppear like this

   ```
   public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
   {
       base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

       if (TodayMessage == null)
       {
           // Add label to view
           TodayMessage = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height))
           {
               TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
               BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray,
               TextColor = UIColor.Black
           };

           // Calculate the values
           var dayOfYear = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
           var leapYearExtra = DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year) ? 1 : 0;
           var daysRemaining = 365 + leapYearExtra - dayOfYear;

           // Display the message
           if (daysRemaining == 1)
           {
               TodayMessage.Text = String.Format("Today is day {0}. There is one day remaining in the year.", dayOfYear);
           }
           else
           {
               TodayMessage.Text = String.Format("Today is day {0}. There are {1} days remaining in the year.", dayOfYear, daysRemaining);
           }

           View.AddSubview(TodayMessage);
       }
   }
   ```

[image]